# Vectorisation of coordinate distances in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to understand Numpy by applying vectorisation. I'm trying to find the fastest function to do it.

```
def get_distances3(coordinates):
    return np.linalg.norm(
        coordinates[:, None, :] - coordinates[None, :, :],
        axis=-1)
coordinates = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
%timeit get_distances3(coordinates)
```

The function above took 10 loops, best of 3: 35.4 ms per loop. From numpy library there's also an np.vectorize option to do it.

```
def get_distances4(coordinates):
  return np.vectorize(coordinates[:, None, :] - coordinates[None, :, :],axis=-1)

%timeit get_distances4(coordinates)
```

I tried with np.vectorize below, yet ended up with the following error.

**TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'**

How can I find vectorization in get_distances4? How should I edit the lsat code in order to avoid the error? I have never used np.vectorize, so I might be missing something.

Comment: Your first solution is already vectorized, no need for `np.vectorize()`

Comment: Would it be possible to vectorize through the np.vectorize()? If so, how?

Comment: @enes perhaps you could provide a follow-up example.  What are you trying to achieve by using `np.vectorize()` that your first example doesn't already do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `np.vectorize()` correctly.  I suggest referring to [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

Vectorize takes as its argument *a function* that is written to operate on *scalar* values, and converts it into a function that can be vectorized over values in arrays according to the Numpy broadcasting rules.  It's basically like a fancy `map()` for Numpy array.

i.e. as you know Numpy already has built-in vectorized versions of many common functions, but if you had some custom function like "my_special_function(x)" and you wanted to be able to call it on Numpy arrays, you could use `my_special_function_ufunc = np.vectorize(my_special_function)`.

In your above example you might "vectorize" your distance function like:

```
>>> norm = np.linalg.norm
>>> get_distance4 = np.vectorize(lambda a, b: norm(a - b))
>>> get_distance4(coordinates[:, None, :], coordinates[None, :, :])
```

However, you will find that this is incredibly slow:

```
>>> %timeit get_distance4(coordinates[:, None, :], coordinates[None, :, :])
1 loop, best of 3: 10.8 s per loop
```

This is because your first example `get_distance3` is already using Numpy's built-in fast implementations of these operations, whereas the `np.vectorize` version requires calling the Python function I defined some 3000 times.

In fact according to the docs:

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

If you want a potentially faster function for converting distances between vectors you could use [`scipy.spacial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist):

```
>>> %timeit get_distances3(coordinates)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop
>>> %timeit distance.pdist(coordinates)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 ms per loop
```

It's worth noting that this has a different return formation.  Rather than a 1000x1000 array it uses a condensed format that excludes `i = j` entries and `i > j` entries.  If you wish you can then use [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform) to convert back to the square matrix format.